# What is the proper way to set initially focused component for a dialog in Swing?

Tags: java, swing, focus, joptionpane

I have a bug lurking where the focus is sporadically not ending up on the text field I want it on after popping up a `JOptionPane` containing the text field.

I eventually boiled it down to a reasonable example:

```
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;

public class FocusIssueTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // The real thing has many more components in there,
                // but I removed them for the demo.
                MyInputPane myInputPane = new MyInputPane();
                myInputPane.showDialog(null);
            }
        });
    }

    public static class MyInputPane extends JPanel {
        private final JTextField textField;

        protected MyInputPane() {
            textField = new JTextField();
            textField.selectAll();
            textField.setColumns(30);

            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            add(textField, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        }

        public boolean showDialog(Component parentComponent) {

            final JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane(
                this, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
                JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);

            JDialog dialog = optionPane.createDialog(
                parentComponent, "Select a Thing");

            /* Attempted solution #1 - wait until the window is active
            dialog.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void windowActivated(WindowEvent event) {
                    textField.requestFocusInWindow();
                }
            });
            */

            /* Attempted solution #2 - camickr's RequestFocusListener
            textField.addAncestorListener(new AncestorListener() {
                @Override
                public void ancestorAdded(AncestorEvent event) {
                    JComponent component = event.getComponent();
                    component.requestFocusInWindow();
                    component.removeAncestorListener(this);
                }

                @Override
                public void ancestorRemoved(AncestorEvent event) {

                }

                @Override
                public void ancestorMoved(AncestorEvent event) {

                }
            });
            */

            /* Attempted solution #3 - HierarchyListener
            textField.addHierarchyListener(new HierarchyListener() {
                @Override
                public void hierarchyChanged(HierarchyEvent event) {
                    Component component = event.getComponent();
                    if ((HierarchyEvent.SHOWING_CHANGED &
                         event.getChangeFlags()) != 0 &&
                            component.isShowing()) {
                        component.requestFocusInWindow();
                        component.removeHierarchyListener(this);
                    }
                }
            });
            */

            // Attempted solution #4 - appears to work but can't be
            // right, because eww.
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    textField.requestFocusInWindow();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

            dialog.setVisible(true);
            Object selectedValue = optionPane.getValue();
            return selectedValue instanceof Integer &&
                   (int) selectedValue == 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Attempted solutions #1 through #3 all fail to put the focus in the text field. Attempted solution #4 works but having to use three levels of nested `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` calls can't possibly be the proper way to do this.

So what *is* the proper way?

I notice that `JOptionPane.showInputDialog`' text field *does* receive focus, so clearly there is a way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the canonical solution, but you could try just one call to queue on the event thread within your window listener. For e.g.,

```
     dialog.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void windowActivated(WindowEvent event) {
           SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
              public void run() {
                 textField.requestFocusInWindow();
              }
           });
        }
     });
```

Other possible "kludges" include using a short single-run Swing timer.

Comment: One definitely doesn't work. Two works most of the time but seems to randomly choose not to work. Three seems fairly solid, but I mean, how can I guarantee that it's OK? Maybe it just fails even less often but still fails. :)

Comment: @Trejkaz: Consider looking at the source code for `JOptionPane.showInputDialog` to see how the Swing coders did it. Yours is a nicely asked question by the way.

Comment: It looks like they maintain a field in BasicOptionPaneUI called inputComponent. If the field is non-null, it is focused right *before* the dialog is displayed. They set it if wantsInput has been set to true but there is otherwise no way to set my own value in (reflection might work, though, and is sort of tempting in a bad way.)

Comment: @camickr has very interesting [code with explanations and in English language](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/03/14/dialog-focus/)

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered subclassing / initializing a JDialog directly instead of using JOptionPane ?

The reason why java does not have a "setFocusInWindow" is because on some platforms it is not possible to directly "set" the focus (as much as request it. )

To me it seems like the call to "setVisible()" is putting a event on the EDT, to make the window visible, which in turn is changing the focus away from your text field.

Comment: I have considered it, but JOptionPane contains a lot of code for rtl layouts, accessibility and other hard stuff that I would rather not duplicate.

Comment: I tend to stay away from JOptionPane simply because it makes writing unit tests 100x more difficult when having to mock out user input responses. 

setVisible blocks on dialogs, and sun does this hacky creation of a new EDT to handle events while the dialog is alive if it is modal.

soo.... create a componentListener and overwrite the "componentResized" method of your for your textfield (which "Should" get called after setVisible(true) is called. Dialogs created by optionPane have their own windowListener which hammers the focus which is definined in JOptionPane.initDialog( ) (

Comment: You're right about it being a pain for unit tests. At work, I get around that particular issue by abstracting the act of asking for information. So the code is never directly displaying an option pane, it's always something like selectThingDisplayer.ask(), which is easily mocked out for tests. It also means that if I do have to switch away from an option pane later, I don't have to change the calls...

Comment: This is similar to my approach for message dialogs and user confirmations ( having a single class which wraps JOptionPane, and then using DI to overwrite it for test cases. )